# How to block Log class developing time?

Tags: android, logging

I am tech lead of my project and i made one class name is `Logs` which is used to print `debug`,`warn`,`info` and `verbose` purpose.

I tell to my team use `Logs` class for print debug log, but no one is follow my rule, I want to do like only `Logs` class allow to print debug msg and other class can not seen [Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class is there any way to do this ?

My class implementation is

```
public class Logs {
    private static String TAG = "test";


    public static void d(String tag, String msg) {
        Log.d(tag, msg);
    }

    public static void e(String tag, String msg, Throwable throwable) {
        Log.e(tag, msg, throwable);
    }

    public static void i(String tag, String msg) {
        Log.i(tag, msg);
    }

    public static void w(String tag, String msg, Throwable throwable) {
        Log.w(tag, msg, throwable);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are team leader. You have power to reject developer commits, in case of not following common rules of your project. You have to teach them to follow rules... teach them these are the common practice.

Comment: problem is on i handled 7 teams at a time to consult them it is very big task because all teams out of india.

Answer (score -1):

**No** you can not do this.

`Log` class will be visible always because it is under `android.util` package.
And you can not remove that class from `util` package.